# How to get a join based on a condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the below sample dataframe as

df1

```
date        ac_pd   
2013-06-15  3.252   
2013-06-30  1.542   
2013-07-15  10.254  
2013-07-31  16.348
```

And, another df contains daily data:

df2

```
date        a_1     a_2     a_3     a_4
03/06/2013  2150    1146    204     22130
04/06/2013  2412    1270    520     23860
25/06/2013  2470    1408.5  610     27690
06/01/2014  2252    1607    793     2180
```

And, I would like to convert df2 monthly data to biweekly date format in df1 by taking an average. for example if df1 has date has 15-06-2003 then it should get a_1 average value between 1-06-2003 to 15-06-2003. There could be chances that every day in a month is not present but we need to take an average of what is available.

```
date        ac_pd   a_1    a_2
2013-06-15  3.252   
2013-06-30  1.542   
2013-07-15  10.254  
2013-07-31  16.348
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `SM` [offset alias](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for semi month end frequency, then remove only `NaN`s rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `df1` with default left join:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=True)

df22 = df2.resample('SM',on='date').mean().dropna(how='all')
print (df22)
               a_1     a_2    a_3      a_4
date                                      
2013-05-31  2281.0  1208.0  362.0  22995.0
2013-06-15  2470.0  1408.5  610.0  27690.0
2013-12-31  2252.0  1607.0  793.0   2180.0

df = df1.join(df22, on='date')
print (df)
        date   ac_pd     a_1     a_2    a_3      a_4
0 2013-06-15   3.252  2470.0  1408.5  610.0  27690.0
1 2013-06-30   1.542     NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN
2 2013-07-15  10.254     NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN
3 2013-07-31  16.348     NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN
```